# Animation when closing bottom modal box

Tags: javascript, css

I try to make an animation when closing my bottom modal box. In fact I'm trying to reproduce the opposite effect of its opening, it comes out of the bottom of the screen and I would like it to go down in the same way when it closes.

I used this question : [CSS Animation when closing modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745289/css-animation-when-closing-modal) but it's not quite the same box and I don't know how to use the code.

Here is the code I use :

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past to have exit animations is using a timeout. For example, you could do this:

```
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  //reset the animation
  modal.style.animation = "fadeIn 400ms";
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.animation = "fadeIn 400ms reverse";

  // Wait for the animation to finish playing, then remove the modal.
  setTimeout(() => {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }, 400)
}
```

Note that the timeout is the same length as the animation. I used the [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) shorthand CSS property to update the animation properties. Hope this helps.

Comment: `setTimeout` can sometimes be unprecise. I'd recommend listening for the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event) event on the modal to determine the exact moment the animation is finished.

Comment: Possibility to have the JS in full or with a snippet or demo ? because on my side the modal box does not reverse the FadeIn. It takes well into account the timeout because the modal box is longer to close but no animation.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found is to reuse the solution of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745289/css-animation-when-closing-modal) I slightly modified the code and animation to adapt it to my modal box that comes out of the bottom. If it can help some.

```js
// Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.classList.add('show');
    }
    
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
        modal.classList.remove('show');
    }
    
    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.classList.remove('show');
        }
    }
```

```css
    .modal {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 0;
      bottom: -50%;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      opacity: 0;
      transition: bottom 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    }

    .modal.show {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;

    }
    
    .close {
      color: white;
      float: right;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .modal-header {
      padding: 2px 16px;
      background-color: #5cb85c;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}
    
    .modal-footer {
      padding: 2px 16px;
      background-color: #5cb85c;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .modal-content {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #fefefe;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 0;
      border: 1px solid #888;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```